# Visual Studio Extension -How to color code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, color-codes

I am writing Visual Studio Extension  Color code. My code is mix of 2 languages. Only one language is colored , so I want to color the second language and I don't know how. Is there something that allows me color code on the  way I want.
I want something like this
[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Bgk.png)

Which part of code provides me to color code?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to provide what's called a "classifier". Here's one example:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1245021/Extending-Visual-Studio-to-Provide-a-Colorful-Lang

In general the interface to look for is "IClassifierProvider".

Answer (score 0):

**In case you are talking about Visual Studio Code:**

You will have to create your own extension. To do so you can follow this guide right [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension). More specifically you should run this command:

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
```

And once the installation is over you run:

```
yo code
```

You should the choose **New Language support** and answer all the questions that will appear. Once it's done you can start defining your language. To do so you should go to the **syntaxes** directory and start editing the <plugin_name>.tmLanguage.json.

In this file you will normally find code examples. [Here](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/blob/master/grammars/MagicPython.cson) is the example of an existing Python extension.

If you pay attention there is sometimes a variable called name of this style "comment.line.number-sign.python". In order to find the possible values for this variable, I would suggest you to take a look [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html#keyword). The choice of this name will define the color of the matching value.

I hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: Your answer seems to apply to Visual Studio Code, while the question was about Visual Studio.

Comment: Ahh you are totally right. Thanks for saying it, I'm gonna mention it in the message! Thanks again